# How to build vim from sources with GUI support?

Tags: gvim, linux, installing

I am trying to build vim from source, especially gvim, to get some of the bug fixes that have been plaguing me in the office repository.

I can compile vim fine but gvim is not being generated due to some library missing. I am sure all I am missing is some -devel packages, but which ones?

The issue is this:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME --enable-multibyte --enable-pythoninterp --with-fea
tures=big --enable-gui=gnome2 --with-x=yes
[...]
checking for X... (cached) libraries , headers 
[...]
checking if X11 header files can be found... no
checking --enable-gui argument... no GUI support
[...]
```

Yet:

```
; sudo yum install -y libX11-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, priorities, remove-with-leaves
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ox.ac.uk
 * epel: mirror.serverbeheren.nl
 * extras: mirror.econdc.com
 * updates: mirror.ox.ac.uk
Package libX11-devel-1.6.0-2.1.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Is there a canonical list anywhere?

Comment: "due to some library missing" is not a very descriptive error...

Comment: Yeah, you *probably* need a -devel package, or maybe something else? I don't know since I don't see the error ;-) There is also not a single authorize list, since Vim has many compile-time options which  influences this (for example, gVim can use several different toolkits)... The general strategy is to see which one you need from the error, install it, and repeat until it doesn't error out.

Comment: Shouldn't [tag:linux] tag be not enough? Compiling process should be the same across different distributions.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I think the issue might be that the OP doesn't know where to look to find such an error. They've pasted the error they can see into their question already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For configuration command you've specified `gnome2` as your main GUI (`--enable-gui=gnome2`), are you sure it's the right one? Or maybe `gnome2` is not enough to enable GUI, so try to add extra `--enable-gui`, `--with-x` parameters.

You can also configure so your GUI would be detected automatically by `--enable-gui=auto`.

Also make sure that you have all your dependencies such as `build-dep` and `vim-gtk` (`sudo yum builddep vim-X11` or `sudo apt-get build-dep vim-gtk`).

If the problem is still happening, check your `config.log` which should be generated by your `./configure` to check exact details of the failure for GUI section.

See also:

- [How to build vim with gui option from sources?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345593/how-to-build-vim-with-gui-option-from-sources)

Comment: The correct `yum` command is `sudo yum-builddep vim-X11`. And this solved my problem.

Comment: for me what fixed it is remove auto conf cache and a make clean

Comment: For me on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS `sudo apt-get build-dep vim-gtk` showed error until I added "Source code"  checkbox in Software&Updates on "Ubuntu Software" tab. Then I made `sudo apt-get update` and command worked.