# Building gvim inside WSL 2 Ubuntu

Tags: gvim, compile-vim, wsl

Details of what already exists inside WSL 2 Ubuntu 20.04 inside Microsot Windows 11:

```
$  vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Feb 01 2022 09:16:32)
Included patches: 1-2269, 3612, 3625, 3669, 3741
Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Huge version with GTK3 GUI.

type [vi|vim|gvim] shows "is hashed" /usr/bin/[vi|vim|gvim]
which is soft-linked as follows:
/usr/bin/[vi|vim|gvim] -> /etc/alternatives/[vi|vim|gvim] -> /usr/bin/vim.gtk3
```

What I did:

```
sudo apt install git make clang libtool-bin libxt-dev libgtk-3-devfg
git clone  https://github.com/vim/vim.git
cd vim/src
make clean
make distclean
./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-gui --enable-gui=gtk3 --with-features=huge
make  && make test
```

Some tests were skipped, and one test failed:

```
Executed 118 tests                       in   0.642854 seconds
../vim -u NONE -U NONE --noplugin --not-a-term -S summarize.vim messages --cmd 'au SwapExists * let v:swapchoice = "e"' | LC_ALL=C LANG=C LANGUAGE=C awk '/Executing Test_/{match($0, "Executing Test_[^\\)]*\\)"); print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) "\r"; fflush()}'

Test results:

Skipped:
        test_balloon_gui.vim: only works in the GUI
        Test_buffer_scheme(): only works on MS-Windows
        Test_job_start_windows(): only works on MS-Windows
        Test_job_with_list_args(): only works on MS-Windows
        Test_no_hang_windows(): only works on MS-Windows
        Test_fuzzy_completion_menu(): only works in the GUI
        Test_crypt_sodium(): sodium feature missing
        Test_head_only_4(): sodium feature missing
        Test_uncrypt_xchacha20(): sodium feature missing
        Test_uncrypt_xchacha20_2(): sodium feature missing
        Test_uncrypt_xchacha20_3_persistent_undo(): sodium feature missing
        Test_uncrypt_xchacha20_invalid(): sodium feature missing
        test_cscope.vim: cscope program not executable
        Test_edit_shift_bs(): only works on MS-Windows
        Test_mac_locale(): osxdarwin feature missing
        Test_browse(): browse feature missing
        Test_browsedir(): browse feature missing
        Test_executable_longname(): only works on MS-Windows
        Test_executable_windows_store_apps(): only works on MS-Windows
        Test_readdirex_sort(): de_DE collation is not available
        Test_resolve_win32(): only works on MS-Windows
        Test_gui_lowlevel_keyevent(): only works on MS-Windows
        Test_set_guifontset(): xfontset feature missing
        Test_iminsert_toggle(): only works in the GUI
        Test_ins_completeslash(): only works on MS-Windows
        Test_issue_7021(): only works on MS-Windows
        test_lua.vim: lua feature missing
        Test_mksession_winpos(): only works in the GUI
        Test_modeline_fails_always(): luadll option not supported
        test_mzscheme.vim: mzscheme feature missing
        Test_normal35_g_cmd4(): output of g< can't be tested currently
        Test_normal_changecase_turkish(): Turkish locale not available
        Test_opt_cdhome(): only works on non-Unix
        Test_bind_in_python(): python feature missing
        test_perl.vim: perl feature missing
        Test_popup_and_preview_autocommand(): python feature missing
        test_python2.vim: python feature missing
        test_python3.vim: python3 feature missing
        test_pyx2.vim: python feature missing
        test_pyx3.vim: python3 feature missing
        test_ruby.vim: ruby feature missing
        Test_shellslash(): shellslash option not supported
        test_shortpathname.vim: only works on MS-Windows
        test_sound.vim: sound feature missing
        Test_win32_symlink_dir(): only works on MS-Windows
        Test_system_with_shell_quote(): only works on MS-Windows
        Test_tabline_tabmenu(): only works in the GUI
        test_tcl.vim: tcl feature missing
        Test_term_mouse_middle_click_no_clipboard(): clipboard support works
        Test_terminal_eof_arg_win32_ctrl_z(): only works on MS-Windows
        Test_balloon_show(): only works in the GUI
        Test_browse(): browse feature missing
        Test_debugbreak(): only works on MS-Windows
        Test_luaeval(): lua feature missing
        Test_mzeval(): mzscheme feature missing
        Test_perleval(): perl feature missing
        Test_py3eval(): python3 feature missing
        Test_pyeval(): python feature missing
        Test_pyxeval(): python feature missing
        Test_rubyeval(): ruby feature missing
        Test_sound_playevent(): sound feature missing
        Test_sound_playfile(): sound feature missing
        Test_sound_stop(): sound feature missing
        Test_test_gui_event(): only works in the GUI
        Test_function_python(): python3 feature missing
        test_windows_home.vim: only works on MS-Windows
        Test_write_file_encoding(): only works on MS-Windows

-------------------------------
Executed:  5168 Tests
 Skipped:    67 Tests
  FAILED:     1 Tests


Failures:
        From test_startup.vim:
        Found errors in Test_geometry():
        command line..script /opt/vim/src/testdir/runtest.vim[468]..function RunTheTest[44]..Test_geometry line 31: Expected '41' but got '-32768'
        command line..script /opt/vim/src/testdir/runtest.vim[468]..function RunTheTest[44]..Test_geometry line 32: Expected '150' but got '-32768'
        command line..script /opt/vim/src/testdir/runtest.vim[468]..function RunTheTest[44]..Test_geometry line 33: Expected '[41, 150]' but got '[-32768, -32768]'

TEST FAILURE
make[1]: *** [Makefile:49: report] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/vim/src/testdir'
make: *** [Makefile:2234: scripttests] Error 2
```

Then created a soft-link to gvim, checked its version and attempted to execute it:

```
Softlink: ../gvim -> src/vim

$ ../gvim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Jul 25 2022 08:24:40)
Included patches: 1-63
Compiled by <username>@w11wslxps
Huge version with GTK3 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
+balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term -gettext           +num64             +textobjects
+browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       +insert_expand     -perl              +title
+channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   +toolbar
+cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
+clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
+clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +vim9script
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           -python3           +virtualedit
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +visual
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +visualextra
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +vreplace
+cscope            +localmap          -ruby              +wildignore
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +windows
+dialog_con_gui    +mksession         +smartindent       +writebackup
+diff              +modify_fname      -sodium            +X11
+digraphs          +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
+dnd               +mouseshape        +spell             +xim
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
+emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         +statusline        +xsmp_interact
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
-farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE -lm -ltinfo -lselinux -lrt -ldl
```

Attempted to execute gvim -- gvim does startup and work as expected but there are some messages on the console during statup:

```
$ ../gvim
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vimrc:
line   25:
E484: Can't open file /usr/share/vim/syntax/syntax.vim
Error detected while processing /home/<username>/.vimrc:
line  231:
E484: Can't open file /usr/share/vim/vimrc_example.vim
failed to load colors/lists/default.vim
```

Questions:

1. How to get the one unsuccessful test to pass?
2. How to install so that the existing version of vim get over-written/deleted?

Comment: You may need additional dependencies. `udo apt-get build-dep vim-gtk)` the following answer could help you:(https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2646/how-to-build-vim-from-sources-with-gui-support)[how to build vim from source]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build vim from sources with GUI support?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2646/how-to-build-vim-from-sources-with-gui-support)

Comment: are you sure, running a graphical application does actually work for WSL2?

Comment: @brabandt yes, the default gvim (version provided in question) runs as expected. Also, the newly built gvim (softlink to src/vim) runs, other than for those messages on the console. Have update the question by mentioning " gvim does startup and work as expected but there are some messages on the console during statup:"

Comment: @user1823664 Please it's *Christian Brabandt*. For me this does not open gvim, because WSL does not find a $DISPLAY. I think there are some special patches applied from MS to make this work from WSL2 with gui

Comment: @brabandt This question is about the (minor) start up error messages and about installing the newly compiled vim so that it overwrites the preexisting installation of vim. Not being able to run gui apps in WSL2 is a different issue; please ask a new question -- running gui apps from WSL requires both WSL2 and Windows 11.

Comment: @user1823664 **Please it is still Christian Brabandt**, never mind, this is the last time I comment here. Then please update the *title* of your question and check your *$VIMRUNTIME*  environment variable. And you seem to have more basic fundamental Unix questions on installation.

Comment: why are you running tests? unless you're messing around with the source code, you don't need to run tests. And the error messages are because you haven't installed vim in proper location. When you did `make`, it by default chose `INSTALL_PREFIX` (or something similar) to be `/usr/`, but since you haven't actually done `make install`, the files haven't been copied to there, and thus g/vim can't find it there. But forget all that. First question first. What are you trynna do? Your steps makes no sense.

Comment: @kadekai -- Running the tests to confirm that the build succeeded. (a) want the latest version of vim/gvim (b) that performs as well as the version installed via "apt-get install vim-gtk3" and (c) remove all vestiges of the existing version.  https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/+question/702569

Comment: Testing is not for users, period. It's for the devs to ensure a new commit didn't break anything. (The rest of what you said I don't understand. Sorry.)